# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unicode, decode

I am working google appengine python 2.5.

I am experiencing unicodedecoderror on following code because myuser name has following value

```
userName     = unicode(userName).encode('utf-8') # äºï¼égãwmj is value in this variable  

userName     = unicode(userName).encode('utf-8')
strData = '{\"Sid\" :1, \"Oppid\" :%s, \"Aid\" :%s, \"EC\" :\"%s\", \"Name\" :\%s"' % (enemyID, userID, userEmpCode,userName)


   params = {'deviceToken'   : oDeviceToken,
              'message'       : strMessage,
              'CertificateId' : certificateId,
              'Data'          : strData
             }


result = urlfetch.fetch(url = url,
             payload = urllib.urlencode(params),
             method  = urlfetch.POST,
             headers = {"Authorization" : authString},
             deadline = 30
             )
```

I am doing the following steps on username to encode it into utf-8 so that I could send it as payload.

```
username = unicode(username).encode(utf-8)
```

I believe the error occurs when I call `urllib.urlencode(params)`

Please guide what is going wrong.. or you can..

and what  should be ultimate strategy to deal with unicode string on appengine python..

I have tried different solutions reading different threads.. but still did not work

Comment: Please provide a stacktrace. And maybe try to produce a minimal working example that does not use variables that are defined elsewhere.

Answer (score 7):

You're problem seems to be that you're calling `unicode(userName)` without an encoding on your already-encoded string, so it "defaults to the current default string encoding", which seems to be `ascii` in your case.

You probably should not call `unicode` in any case, if you know it's a unicode value, you're fine already, if not, call `.decode` with the correct encoding.
If you're unsure, test using `isinstance` since trying to decode a unicode value will result in yet another error.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when porting Python 3 code from Ubuntu Linux 14.04 to FreeBSD 10.3. The latter system seems to use ASCII by default instead of UTF-8 when opening files with Python 3.4.4.

Specifying `encoding='utf-8'` with the file `open` command resolved my issue:

```
open('filepath', encoding='utf-8')
```